# Show video in mono application

Tags: mono, gtk#, libvlcsharp

I created simple desktop application in mono and I added control from LibVLCSharp project to show video and it works but the video is tugging itself on Raspberry Pi.
Are in mono other possibilities to show fluently video?

**The code** which I have and try to run here: 
https://github.com/artbase/monoappwithgtkvideo

**The logs** what I get below /usr/bin/xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma
for output default

> [021b1658] pulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection
>   failure: Connection refused
>
> Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory
>
> [6a200c80] xcb_xv vout display error: no available XVideo adaptor

Comment: tugging itself? Please share more details, including code and logs.

Comment: Does VLC play the video fine on your raspberry pi? do you have the latest raspbian? the latest raspberry version? looks like a hardware acceleration issue.

Comment: Sure, I added the code and logs.

Comment: When I run the VLC on raspberry it works fine. I have Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+

Comment: tugging itself :) ok mayby I should use word choppy. The video is choppy.

Comment: Share full logs from the beginning of your app. Share full logs from VLC on the pi.

Comment: Remove `Core.Initialize`

Comment: which libvlc version you have?